# Oracle to MSSQL migration issue ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We are trying to migrate from oracle to MSSQL.

We are facing issue while migrating.

1. One of the oracle table is not getting copied in SQL with below error:

> Errors: ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

But with SQL developer there was no issues i.e. If I run select command on all the column I don't get any error.

I also tried to use following function to convert the column, but didn't really help.

```
select convert(column1,'US7ASCII','WE8ISO8859P1') from table;
```

please suggest.

Comment: What method are you using to insert the data from Oracle to SQL Server?  What are the column definitions of the table on each side?

Comment: we are using SSMA tool for migration.